For a DatePicker Component, how can I only display the Calender Icon?
I am trying to use the DatePicker component from MUI to choose my date. So far I have accomplished the following,
            <DatePicker
                name="goalDateDatePicker"
                minDate={dayjs(new Date()).add(1, 'days')}
                // @ts-ignore - Remove the null type check as we will never receive it.
                onChange={(v: Dayjs | null) => null}
                slotProps={{
                    textField: {
                        InputProps: {
                            placeholder:"",
                            value: null,
                            startAdornment: (
                                <IconButton style={{ padding: 0 }}>
                                    { null }
                                </IconButton>
                            ),
                        },
                    },
                }}
            />

Unfortunately, although the input is now blank, I cannot find a way to remove the input option entirely and also the border. I simply want to select the calender icon to choose a date so that I can use the date elsewhere.
I am using slotProps as per the reccomendation and I have also read the customization section but I cannot find an example that suits only presenting the calender icon and making it clickable to select a date.

const EditCalendarIconDatePicker: React.FC<Props> = ({ onDateSelection }) => {
    const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState<Dayjs | null>(dayjs());
    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

    const handleDateChange = (date: Dayjs | null) => {
        setSelectedDate(date);
        onDateSelection(date);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <IconButton 
                onClick={() => setOpen(true)}
                id="calendar-icon-button"
            >
                <EditCalendarTwoToneIcon/>
            </IconButton>

            <DatePicker
                open={open}
                onClose={() => setOpen(false)}
                value={selectedDate}
                onAccept={handleDateChange}
                slotProps={{
                    popper: {
                        anchorEl: document.getElementById('calendar-icon-button'), // Anchor the position to be at the Icon
                        placement: 'bottom-start'
                    },
                    textField: {
                        InputProps: { style: { display: 'none' } }, // Hide the input field
                    },
                }}
            />
        </>
    );
};

